# Serialise inner JsonValue

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data

I am trying to use the Json type provider to create types and iterate over a list. But, I also need to access the serialised json of each item.

Here is what I have

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data"
#r "nuget: System.Text.Json"
 
open FSharp.Data
open System.Text.Json

type Users = JsonProvider<"""{"users":[{"id":1, "name": "John"}, {"id":2, "name": "Paul"}]}""">

let data = Users.GetSample().Users

let printProduct (id:int, userJson: string) = 
    printfn "%i %s" id userJson

let returnIdandJson() =
    data |> Seq.map(fun x-> (printProduct (x.Id, JsonSerializer.Serialize x)))


returnIdandJson()
```

This prints

```
1 {"JsonValue":{"Tag":3,"IsString":false,"IsNumber":false,"IsFloat":false,"IsRecord":true,"IsArray":false,"IsBoolean":false,"IsNull":false,"_Pri:false,"IsNull":false,"_Print":"{\r\n  \u0022id\u0022: 1,\r\n  \u0022name\u0022: \u0022John\u0022\r\n}"}}
2 {"JsonValue":{"Tag":3,"IsString":false,"IsNumber":false,"IsFloat":false,"IsRecord":true,"IsArray":false,"IsBoolean":false,"IsNull":false,"_Pri:false,"IsNull":false,"_Print":"{\r\n  \u0022id\u0022: 2,\r\n  \u0022name\u0022: \u0022Paul\u0022\r\n}"}}
```

What I want is

```
1 {"id":1, "name": "John"}
2 {"id":2, "name": "Paul"}
```

Is there a way I can access and serialise the inner list items from  JsonValue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the original JSON via the `.JsonValue` property that exists on every object returned by the provider. This property returns type `JsonValue`, which you can programmatically analyze if you wanted (e.g. calling its `Properties()` method or some such), and it also has a handly `ToString` implementation that just returns the serialized JSON:

```
let printProduct (id:int, userJson: string) = 
    printfn "%i %s" id userJson

let returnIdandJson() =
    data |> Seq.map(fun x-> (printProduct (x.Id, string x.JsonValue)))
```